# T-SQL Server Agent Formating Message for sp_notify_operator

Tags: html, t-sql, format, operator-keyword, sp-send-dbmail

I would like to format my message for the Stored Procedure **sp_notify_operator**

But it does not take the Parameter **@body_format = 'HTML'** like *sp_send_dbmail*.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_notify_operator 
    @profile_name = 'Mail Service',  
    @name = @Operator,  
    @body = @MSG,
    @subject = 'Automated Success Message' ;
```

It is important to use this Stored Procedure, because I want to inform one Operator Profile.

Somebody any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do the same thing with msdb..sp_send_dbmail

```
SELECT @body =N' body ' 

SELECT @subject =  ' subject ';

select @operator = email_address from msdb.dbo.sysoperators
WHERE name = 'operator name'

EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail
    @subject =  @subject,  
    @body =  @body, 
    @body_format = 'HTML',
    @recipients = @operator
```